# ASP.Net Core Sql Session Persistence

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-core

I've written a ASP.Net Core application that uses SQL based session storage. 
When I run the application via visual studio, the session object persists builds and starting/stopping IIS express, however, when I deploy it to the server (Win server 2012R2), an app pool recycle causes it to lose session state. - Edit, actually a restart of my computer, which obviously ends an underlying process, causes me to lose session in visual studio also.

My ConfigureServices:

```
        // Serializer settings have been changed so that the JSON response sends the same case, not lower case first letter as default
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

        // Builder to access the config
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var config = builder.Build();            

        // Get and configure the session timeout
        int SessionTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(config["AppSettings:SessionTimeout"]);
        services.AddSession(s =>
        {
            s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SessionTimeout);                
        }
        );

        // Get the session state datebase location
        var AspStateConnectionString = config["AppSettings:ConnectionStrings:ASPStateConnectionString"];
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(o =>
        {
            o.ConnectionString = AspStateConnectionString;
            o.SchemaName = "dbo";
            o.TableName = "Sessions";
        });
```

My Configure:

```
        // Configure to use session
        app.UseSession();

        // Pass context to CoreSessionManager class and ContextPerRequest
        var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        CoreSessionManager.Configure(httpContextAccessor);
        CoreLibrary.ContextPerRequest.Configure(httpContextAccessor);

        // Configure the routes - defaults to login page.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");
        });
```

The CoreSessionManager class does the work around the actual session objects:

```
    private static IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    public static UserDetail UserDetail
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("UserDetail") != null)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetail>(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserDetail"));

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserDetail", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }
    }
```

If this UserDetails is null, the user is kicked out to the login screen.
Is there something I am missing? Do I need to add in some other configurations?

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: Seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup ASPState on your sql server?

[This link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/104082/configuring-asp-session-state-on-sql-server) might help you to setup ASPState.

Or follow this steps:

Open a command prompt and locate the following path:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 based on your OS version and .NET version
Use the following statement:

when using default ASPState database and SQL security, type the command below:

```
aspnet_regsql -S serverName -U UserName -P Password -ssadd -sstype p
```

Using default ASPState database and windows security, type the command below:

```
aspnet_regsql -S serverName -E -ssadd -sstype p
```

Using custom database and SQL security, type the command below:

```
aspnet_regsql -d TableName -S serverName -U UserName -P Password -ssadd -sstype c
```

Comment: I did. I ran the SQL command directly as per this link:
[link(]http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/292/configuring-sql-server-for-session-state-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc)
I can see the entries populating and when I change the login string, the sessions don't create.

Comment: Also, I may be wrong, but I believe that is for creating the old version of the ASPState tables. It has a different structure in ASP.Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasn't working was because I had to enable Load User Profile in the application pool in IIS.